# sharepoint list form or form library form

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath2010

I am new to infopath, I would like to create form with infopath, but i do not know which template i have to select

```
     1- sharepoint list form
     2- form library form
```

Actually i have problem with form library form, i think when it saves data as a xml file and does not save in list, in future i faced problem.
I would like to design master/detail form but i am afraid of form library form, because it does not save data in list and i do not know how i have to use these xml files.

can I create and save master/detail form in share point list and do insert/update/delete?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "Customize Form" in the lit ribbon. After making the change, just publish the form. The form would be saved in SharePoint List.

Like this:

[image]